# Creating css grid of images with parallax effect

Tags: css, css-grid, parallax

A basic full browser parallax background image can be achieved relatively simply with the following:

```
    <div class = "parallax">
<!--image here -->
    </div>

.parallex{
  background: url(*url*);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

I have attempted to put grid items inside the .parallax div and set individual `background-image` values on those:

```
 <div class = "parallax">
      <div id = "img1">
      </div>
      <div id = "img2">
      </div>
      <div id = "img3">
      </div>
      <!--etc-->
   </div>

.parallex{
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
height: 100vh;
   }
#image1{
background-image: url(*url1*);
}
#image2{
background-image: url(*url2*);
}
```

but that did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not confident that css-grid is the correct tag for this since I think what you're wanting is an actual grid of elements, rather than a css grid. Besides that, I'd bet that the reason you're not seeing the parallax effect is because you're trying to see children scrolling against their fixed parent. The parent is going to take its children with it. You need to separate the two.